# Cannot import a module with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am not able to import a module under the simplest of implementations.  I have looked at other SO posts and they are much more complicated and hard for me to follow.  I imagine this is a Python configuration error but I would like to be sure before I go digging up any libraries or path statements if it is not necessary.

[modone.py]:

```
import modtwo.py

mod1 = "I am module #1"

print(mod1)

print(mod2)
```

[modtwo.py]:

```
mod2 = "I am module #2"
```

Doesn't get more basic than that... yet this is the output that I receive in the shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1521, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OTI\Scripts\Python\Script1\modone.py", line 1, in <module>
    import modtwo.py
ImportError: No module named 'modtwo.py'; modtwo is not a package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
import modtwo   # no .py extension

print(modtwo.mod2)    # mod2 is namespaced to its module.
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
from modtwo import mod2

print(mod2)
```

While the second option may be more tempting (shorter when you use `mod2` often, it doesn't namespace `mod2` and thus could clash with an identically named variable in your `modone` module.

Comment: Thank you.  I could not move on with my lessons until I had this understood.

Answer (score 2):

[Importing is done by specifying the module name, not the module filename; the interpreter will figure out the appropriate filename to use.](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

```
import modtwo
```